# Remove whitespace from areaspline chart at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, spline

I am trying to create an areaspline chart. Why is the bottom most value giving me white spaces?

Here is my code:

```
Highcharts.chart(chart_area, {
        chart: {
            height: 550,
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        colors: ['#3397DA', '#5CB85C', '#F9C822', '#E64C3C', '#756BB1', '#76C3FF', '#8CD58C', '#FFDA6A', '#FF7683', '#BFB7F4'],
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%d. %b',
                month: '%b&#39;%y',
                year: '%Y'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            areaspline: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: 'circle'
                }
            },
            series: {
                turboThreshold: 1000000,
                cursor: 'pointer'
            },
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'xyz'
            },
        }],
        series: series
    });
```

It is a normal stacked chart but the bottom is giving me whitespaces:

[image: WHitespace]

WHat am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle? On this demo, everything looks good: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/04agtxcj/

Comment: @WojciechChmiel. I am not able to render it to fiddle but here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/rprak0605/Ljcqr1xt/6/

Comment: Your Highcharts code looks good. I have to check data but in your fiddle there are couple variables missing. Could you try to simplify it? Use the final data from the plotted chart.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel, simplify it how? I mean this is the data from my plotted chart. what variables are missing? I can clear those for you

Comment: Error from the browser console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: series_brow is not defined`. Open the console and you will see it.